# How to add required attribute to html5 form radio input using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I want to produce a radio button like this:

```
     <input type="radio" name="quest0" value="a" required>
```

I am doing like this

```
 echo form_radio("quest0","a");
```

But how can I add `required` attribute using Codeigniter form helper.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it this way.(I did not tested it)

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'quest0',
    'value'       => 'a',
    'required'       => 'required'
);

echo form_radio($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '1', TRUE); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '2'); ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add other attributes like `id`, `data-*`, `required` in 4th parameter of `form_radio()` function, try this code

```
echo form_radio("quest0","a", false,"required id=\"quest0\"");
```

Comment: Girish, 3rd Parameter must be a **BOOLEAN** value. TRUE or FALSE. Refer the [source code] (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L459). Am assuming that the question is related to CI Version 2.0

Comment: sorry, you right, i forgot 3rd parameter for `form_input()`, and `form_select, form_radio()` function get element attribute in 4th parameter

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write as shown by @Shaiful Islam.

Other way is to write as below:
`echo form_radio("quest0","a", FALSE, "required=required");`

Refer the [Source Code - Form Helper - Line 459](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L459)

 You are passing the other parameters as **EXTRA** attribute